# How to create a new table in Directory in QTreeView?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyside

I'm trying a create a new Folder in Directory in QTreeview by Pyside. I'm searching many website, but no one can give me the answer. I just want to know what will I have to research ?

Please, give me some advice.
Thank you

Comment: Please give more details about what you are trying to achieve. What *specific* parts of it are you having difficulty with?

Comment: I have a code, and i already finish to get Directory in QTreeView, after that i want to right click the folder and create a new folder inside, but i don't know how to start with it. I just want some one can give me some advices to let me start with it.

Comment: I doubt that you really searched many websites. Among the first results I get http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084778/qtreewidget-for-file-tree-and-sub-folders or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144830/how-to-create-folder-view-in-pyqt-inside-main-window which should already help you further.